# How do I slice the last 11 IP's off of this 192.168.0.0/24 network using the ipaddress module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Completely new to coding.

**What I'm trying to do:** Return IP addresses in the 192.168.0.0/24 network that doesn't include even numbered IP's or the last 10 (so dont include 192.168.0.244 to 192.168.0.254)

Some images:

1. [In this image, each IP is considered as 4 separate integers, is that right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVf5w.png)
2. [Here is where I've tried to put in an empty list and append only the uneven IP's to valid_net, but it came back with weird results. So I tried splitting it again but it comes back with multiple lists (an array?) and I can't use valid_net = valid_net[:-11] to cut out the last 10 IP's because it comes back with an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j42Ob.png)
3. [The error, (only returns empty [])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ics6M.png)
4. [Some testing I was doing to see how it works...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyNaQ.png)

**The code for you if needed:**

```
import ipaddress

net = ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/24')
for addresses in net:
    allowable_ip = int(addresses.exploded.split('.')[-1]) % 2 == 0
    if not allowable_ip:
        print(addresses)
```

and

```
import ipaddress

net = ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/24')
valid_net = []

for addresses in net:
    allowable_ip = int(addresses.exploded.split('.')[-1]) % 2 == 0
    if not allowable_ip:
        valid_net = (addresses.exploded.split(','))
        print(valid_net[:-11])
```

Thank you to anyone who helps!

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data, include them as **text** in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

`net = ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/24')` is a generator, you can make a list of the values it generates by calling `list` on it, then slice it.

You can then keep only the addresses whose `int` value is even:

```
import ipaddress

net = ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/24')

# we make a list of the addresses and exclude the last 11 ones
addresses = list(net)[:-12]

# and only keep the odd ones
addresses = [address for address in addresses if int(address) % 2 == 1]

print(addresses)
# [IPv4Address('192.168.0.1'), IPv4Address('192.168.0.3'), IPv4Address('192.168.0.5'),
# ...
#  IPv4Address('192.168.0.239'), IPv4Address('192.168.0.241'), IPv4Address('192.168.0.243')]
```